# Prisma ORM not able to select a range of longitude and latitude data

Tags: python, prisma

I'm trying to create an API endpoint to query my database based on some filter parameters provided in the URL.

example:
http://localhost:3000/roles?ethnicity=1&gender=8&longitude=0

All of my queries are working except for longitude and latitude, now I've tried a plethora of different formats for the query but here is the function.

```
@app.route("/roles")
def get_roles():
    ethnicity = request.args.getlist("ethnicity")
    gender = request.args.getlist("gender")
    location = request.args.getlist("location")
    productiontype = request.args.getlist("productiontype")
    roletype = request.args.getlist("roletype")
    minAge = request.args.get("minAge", None)
    maxAge = request.args.get("maxAge", None)
    longitude = request.args.get("longitude", None)
    latitude = request.args.get("latitude", None)

    print(
        f"Finding Roles -- ethnicity: {ethnicity} gender: {gender} location: {location} productiontype: {productiontype} roletype: {roletype}"
    )

    where = {}
    if len(gender) > 0:
        where["gender_match"] = {
            "some": {"gender": {"id": {"in": [int(id) for id in gender]}}}
        }

    if len(ethnicity) > 0:
        where["ethnicity_match"] = {
            "some": {"ethnicity": {"id": {"in": [int(id) for id in ethnicity]}}}
        }

    if len(productiontype) > 0:
        where["production_type_match"] = {
            "some": {
                "productiontype": {"id": {"in": [int(id) for id in productiontype]}}
            }
        }

    if len(roletype) > 0:
        where["role_type_match"] = {
            "some": {"roletype": {"id": {"in": [int(id) for id in roletype]}}}
        }

    if longitude is not None and latitude is not None:
        minLat = float(latitude) - 0.5
        maxLat = float(latitude) + 0.5
        minLong = float(longitude) - 0.5
        maxLong = float(longitude) + 0.5
        
        where["location_match"] = {
            "some": {
                "location": {
                    "AND": [
                        {"latitude": {"gte": minLat}},
                        {"latitude": {"lte": maxLat}},
                        {"longitude": {"gte": minLong}},
                        {"longitude": {"lte": maxLong}},
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

    if minAge is not None and maxAge is not None:
        where["OR"] = [
            {"min_age": {"lte": int(maxAge)}},
            {"max_age": {"gte": int(minAge)}},
        ]
    elif minAge is not None:
        where["min_age"] = {"gte": int(minAge)}

    elif maxAge is not None:
        where["max_age"] = {"lte": int(maxAge)}

    print(where)

    roles = prisma.role.find_many(
        where=where,
        include={
            "ethnicity_match": {"include": {"ethnicity": True}},
            "gender_match": {"include": {"gender": True}},
            "location_match": {"include": {"location": True}},
            "project": True,
            "role_type_match": {"include": {"roletype": True}},
            "production_type_match": {"include": {"productiontype": True}},
            "rate": True,
        },
    )

    return [role.model_dump_json() for role in roles]
```

Printed Where Before Query
`{'location_match': {'some': {'location': {'AND': [{'latitude': {'gte': -118.8870991}}, {'latitude': {'lte': -117.8870991}}, {'longitude': {'gte': 33.6395597}}, {'longitude': {'lte': 34.6395597}}]}}}}`

Example of valid Role

```
{
  "id": 87,
  "name": "Detective TAIPA",
  "created": "2024-01-14T06:56:08.001000Z",
  "project_id": 50,
  "driver_role_id": "bs4846374",
  "min_age": 40,
  "max_age": 50,
  "deadline": "2024-01-22T06:00:00Z",
  "role_url": "https://www.backstage.com/casting/all-want-for-christmas-is-you-2756643/detective-taipa-4846374/",
  "description": "Detective Taipa appears in the scene of the search for the main character, after the accident. The date is 02/06",
  "status": null,
  "role_asset": null,
  "actor_role": null,
  "ethnicity_match": [],
  "gender_match": [
    {
      "role_id": 87,
      "gender_id": 1,
      "gender": {
        "id": 1,
        "driver": "backstage",
        "gender": "Female",
        "gender_match": null,
        "actor_gender": null
      },
      "role": null
    }
  ],
  "location_match": [
    {
      "role_id": 87,
      "location_id": 29,
      "location": {
        "id": 29,
        "formatted_name": "Studio City, Los Angeles, CA, USA",
        "latitude": 34.1395597,
        "longitude": -118.3870991,
        "driver": "backstage",
        "google_place_id": "ChIJ9QK_aQm-woARDtBe_FLmNZA",
        "location_match": null,
        "actor_location": null
      },
      "role": null
    },
    {
      "role_id": 87,
      "location_id": 3,
      "location": {
        "id": 3,
        "formatted_name": "Los Angeles, CA, USA",
        "latitude": 34.0549076,
        "longitude": -118.242643,
        "driver": "backstage",
        "google_place_id": "ChIJE9on3F3HwoAR9AhGJW_fL-I",
        "location_match": null,
        "actor_location": null
      },
      "role": null
    }
  ],
  "production_type_match": [
    {
      "role_id": 87,
      "production_type_id": 10,
      "productiontype": {
        "id": 10,
        "production_type": "Feature Film",
        "driver": "backstage",
        "production_type_match": null,
        "actor_project_type": null
      },
      "role": null
    }
  ],
  "rate": null,
  "project": {
    "id": 50,
    "title": "ALL WANT FOR CHRISTMAS IS YOU",
    "created": "2024-01-14T06:56:07.993000Z",
    "driver_origin": "backstage",
    "driver_project_id": "bs2756643",
    "description": "An Independent film for TV A Christmas movie. The script involves a singer’s emotional journey to love, through grief, and a second chance at love. She falls deeply in love with a guy who disappears and is believed dead. She marries a lawyer who is deeply in love with her. Love #1 reappears along with the complications that follow.",
    "project_url": "https://www.backstage.com/casting/all-want-for-christmas-is-you-2756643/",
    "project_info": "primary_contact: '*The film is being Directed by a highly acclaimed Award-winning\n Director.'\nproduction_company: MEDIA FACTORY INC\nproduction_info: It will be provided later\nproduction_url: ''\n",
    "asset": null,
    "genre_match": null,
    "role": null
  },
  "role_type_match": [
    {
      "role_id": 87,
      "role_type_id": 3,
      "role": null,
      "roletype": {
        "id": 3,
        "role_type": "Day Player",
        "driver": "backstage",
        "role_type_match": null,
        "actor_role_type": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "application": null
}
```

Query
`http://localhost:3000/roles?longitude=34.1395597&latitude=-118.3870991`

I've tried just querying for a longitude gte: minLong and it does function properly, but as soon as I try and query for a range it returns nothing. No errors, just an empty list. Yes i'm positive there are values that match the expected query. I'd really appreciate any help, I've tried all different combinations of the clause I'll list some below

```
roles = prisma.role.find_many(
    where={
        'location_match': {
            'some': {
                'AND': [
                    {'location': {'longitude': {'lte': 34.6395597, 'gte': 33.6395597}}},
                    {'location': {'latitude': {'lte': -117.8870991, 'gte': -118.8870991}}}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
)
```

```
roles = prisma.role.find_many(
    where={
        'location_match': {
            'some': {
                'location': {
                    'longitude': {'lte': 34.8, 'gte': 33.3},
                    'latitude': {'lte': -117.49, 'gte': -118.99}
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

```
if longitude is not None and latitude is not None:
    where["location_match"] = {
        "some": {
            "location": {
                "longitude": {
                    "lte": float(longitude) + 0.75,
                    "gte": float(longitude) - 0.75,
                },
                "latitude": {
                    "lte": float(latitude) + 0.75,
                    "gte": float(latitude) - 0.75,
                },
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).